# Postgres Names of employees that do not work on any project

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to retrieve the names of people who did work on every project in PostgreSQL.

I got a table named `employees` with their

- names
- ssn

My second table is called `works_on` and contains:

- ssn
- pnum

The third table i got is called `Project` and contains:

- pname
- pnum

Now I tried the following:

```
SELECT fname,lname
FROM employee w
JOIN works_on wa ON (wa.ssn = w.ssn) JOIN project pa ON(wa.pnum = pa.pnum)
WHERE ...
```

The problem is that i have no clue what to put at the `WHERE` statement (i'm looking for something like the division operator in relational algebra)

Comment: I tried reversing it but i cant find the right solution